# "Unrasterize" UIView layer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

I have created a UIView with three subviews(UIButtons).

I then added this to a collectionView as a subview.(like a menu)

This of course slows down the FPS..
To make it not affect the scroll performance, I rasterize the UIView's layer.
This works as intended, but i now want to "unrasterize" the UIView layer when the animation stops so that I'm able to use the buttons again.

Any tips? Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

I have tried:

```
[myView setNeedsLayout];
```

And

```
myView.layer.shouldRasterize = NO;
[myView.layer setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Don't call setNeedsDisplay on the layer, call it on the view: [myView setNeedsDisplay], this should cause it to re-render the view and layer hierarchy.

Comment: @MightyLeader Add it as an answer and I'll approve it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call setNeedsDisplay on the layer, call it on the view: [myView setNeedsDisplay], this should cause it to re-render the view and layer hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

It might be as simple as setting the view's layer property `shouldRasterize` to `NO`.

As pointed out by MightyLeader my suspicion that the fix is in the things you tried turned out to be true. View not layer:

```
[myView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: I don't ask questions here before I've tried almost everything. That's of course the first thing Ive tried.

Comment: Great. Clearly, nobody could know this. Maybe you should tell us all the other things you have tried. The fix might be buried there. Please include these in the question by editing it.